# Function that returns its argument, named by itself

Tags: r

Is there a function in base R or a package which takes a list as argument and returns this list with the names set to the list items? Something along these lines:

```
named.list <- function(l) { names(l) <- l; l }
```

This is useful for the `l?ply` functions in `plyr` -- these functions keep the names of the argument list. Compare:

```
llply(c('a', 'b', 'c'), function(x) paste0('(', x, ')'))
```

> ```
>  [[1]]
>  [1] "(a)"
>
>  [[2]]
>  [1] "(b)"
>
>  [[3]]
>  [1] "(c)"
> ```

```
llply(named.list(c('a', 'b', 'c')), function(x) paste0('(', x, ')'))
```

> ```
>  $a
>  [1] "(a)"
>
>  $b
>  [1] "(b)"
>
>  $c
>  [1] "(c)"
> ```

Comment: Not quite clear what your question is. Does `?setNames` help?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this for example?:

```
ll <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
ll <- setNames(ll,ll)
 ll
  a   b   c 
"a" "b" "c"
```